# Returning to D&D from 2nd Edition, what are the things I should look out for

Tags: dnd-5e, adnd-2e

I have agreed to introduce a friend to D&D but I haven't played since AD&D 2nd Edition. I was more often a player than a DM but I am okay with performing that role. I will be starting our part off with the 5th edition Starter Set but is there anything I need to be aware/careful of making the transition?